# Differences between Scope Chain and Closure

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, scoping, scope-chain

According to **scope chain** inner functions can access to outer functions, but at the same time we are accessing outer function through **closure**, then what is difference? Can anyone explain differences between scope chain and closure? My version is that scope chain is just a rule and closure is explanation of how this rule works.

Question is about differences between Scoping and Closure

```
function outer() {
  a = 10;
   function inner() {
    b = 10;
    console.log(a + b);
  };
  return inner()
}

console.log(outer());  //logs: 20
```

Comment: Closure just emphasizes more, that the inner function actually remembers the scope it was created in, e.g. when you return the function, and call it in some other scope.

Comment: That is not a useful demonstration of a closure. `return inner`; `outer()()` would demonstrate it better…